# Detect color change on DevExpress MVC ColorEdit component

Tags: devexpress

Using the MVC @Html.DevExpress().ColorEdit component I couldn't find a way to detect color changed by user.The is no "ClientSideEvents" on this control.The DevExpress Help mention a "ColorChanged" event but after exhaustive search couldn't find anything related. Bellow is the code that is working:

```
@Html.DevExpress().ColorEdit(s => {
    s.Name = "ColorEdit";
    s.Properties.AllowUserInput = true;
    s.ClientEnabled = true;
}).GetHtml()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the "ColorChanged" event in "Properties". Also make sure to set the property "EnableClientSideAPI" to true.

```
@Html.DevExpress().ColorEdit(s => {
    s.Name = "ColorEdit";
    s.Properties.AllowUserInput = true;
    s.ClientEnabled = true;
    s.Properties.EnableClientSideAPI = true;
    s.Properties.ClientSideEvents.ColorChanged = "onColorChanged";
}).GetHtml()
```

Javascript:

```
function onColorChanged(s, e) {
    alert("color has changed");
}
```